# How to install a home made dll in order it is found by wine?

Tags: dll, installation, cross-compiling, wine

I am developping a multi-platform application under Linux. To build the Windows versions, I make use of cross-compiling with MinGW. For "first" tests, I am using wine. First, I have started with MinGW32 and wine configured for Windows XP.

I need to build tier dll and my own dll. Build is alright. If I copy them in C:\windows\system32\ and run my application which use these dll under wine, it does not find them. If I put a copy of the dll in the same directory than the application, it works.

I have tried :

- ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/
- /root/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/

If I run the explorer (wine explorer), and browse into C:\windows\system32\ , my dll are not there !

Thus, **how can I make wine find home made dlls ?** I have had a look at winecfg and winetricks, but they are of no help.

Cheers,

Laurent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an installer for your application, using nsis or something, and creating a package that includes your dll and application. Then install that installer using wine.